# How to check a facebook Page is liked by a user?

Tags: javascript, facebook

i have a like button on my page, i just want to check weather a user has like the page or not. following is my code. i am showing the faces of those users as well who liked the page.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="my-page-url" data-width="175" height="400" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false" border_color="#CCCCCC"></div>
```

Thanks in Advance
Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0):

FB.api('/me', function(response) {
         var user_id = response.id;
         var page_id = your_page_id;
         var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
         var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);
          the_query.wait(function(rows) {
              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                 //do whatever you want to do 
              } else {
                 //not liked..
              }
          });
        });